# This class was deprecated in API level R. - what does it mean?

Tags: android

I look at the documentation on [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask). It contains such statement:

> This class was deprecated in API level R.

I look at the table of available versions of the Android API: [Codenames, Tags, and Build Numbers](https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers)
I don’t see any API level R there. What does API level R mean? What is it version? Where can I see a document in which this version of the API is mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R is the code name for upcoming Android 11.

But even if the class gets deprecated, it will probably stay araound for a couple of years. There will just not be any more changes/improvements for it.

Also there's a lot of other, simpler ways to run code in the background nowadays.

Comment: So, what does R stand for?  Resources?

Comment: All major Android versions have an internal version code in form of a letter and/or word (mostly sweets). From Eclair, Froyo, Gingerbread ... Kitkat ... Oreo ... The current Android 10 has the code Q (no official sweet name) and the next one will be R. Also see here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history